# Why does custom SVG Icon style change after i use second one in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

I'm setting up a new angular project.

i register custom svg with `matIconRegistry` in AppModule.

here's demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozjwe4)

When i add second svg first one gets the style of second one.

You can change the position of each `mat-icon` and see the result.

Comment: they use the same class names i.e. cls-1 and class names are global.

Answer (score -1):

icon
Change mat-icon CSS line-height from 24px to 20px to make icon position exactly in the center of the ripple circle. With 24px it seems to be closer to the bottom.